# Java Scheduling Calendar

Tags: java, calendar, scheduling

I have a j2ee web application which supports scheduling of execution of jobs. I am looking for a free calendar component written in java which allows scheduling functionalities as well as capable of changing view mode of tasks either by viewing taks for whole  year, month view, week view, day view. Do you have any suggestion.

Im sorry something came up with the implementation. I dnt have to use this calendar for triggering or calling jobs. I just need to retrieve schedules from database and display it in diff view modes. SO it's just some kind of GUI functionality

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Quartz Scheduler to get your task view modes you would need to iterate through your triggers and use [TriggerUtils.computeFireTimesBetween(Trigger trigg, Calendar cal, Date from, Date to)](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/org/quartz/TriggerUtils.html#computeFireTimesBetween%28org.quartz.Trigger,%20org.quartz.Calendar,%20java.util.Date,%20java.util.Date%29).

Maybe you could develop a Quartz Scheduler JobStore => iCal component (by using iCal4J).

There may be other solutions => http://java-source.net/open-source/job-schedulers

Comment: i have update above. so maybe there's something out there not that complicated as quartz. :D

Answer (score 0):

I've  been doing some research on a PHP Open Source Calendar. My use case is for providing public/private group calendars for the scheduling of appointments. In my search I came across what appears to be a fairly well developed and modular java app (jboss/apache components) at the following site:
http://www.bedework.org/bedework/

This is the next generation from the original UW Calendar project.

Not sure you need all the functionality provided, but it will definitely handle scheduling of jobs.