# Rad scheduler in java

Tags: java, radscheduler

Are there any application in Java which resemble **Rad Scheduler of telerik**?

Answer (score 0):

Telerik ASP.NET AJAX Scheduler is a nice Scheduler similar to outlook and google calendar. You can refer [here](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-java-calendar).

For open source solution refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446084/java-scheduling-calendar). You will find many options like Bedework, iCal4j, CalDAV4j etc.